# Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.4'` succeeds before bundling. ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I try to Create Rails Apps but i keep getting this error with nokigiri. Did anyone had this issue before ?

```
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.4'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

i tried to install the gem but still no improvement. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`xcode-select --install`

Also, Nokogiri requires `libiconv`, so you may need to install it and install the gem again with options `--with-iconv-lib` and/or `--with-iconv-include` specified.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! Didn't need the extra flags